# How do I access the names of the files in a Corpus object in R?

Tags: r

I have a Corpus object in R that has read multiple files from a directory. Now, I want to access the list of file names inside that object. How can I do that?

Comment: Answered my own question below

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question here for other's benefit.

So if you have a Corpus object docs in R, do the following to access the file name of the first document

```
attr(docs[[1]], "ID")
```

Answer (score 1):

`file.names <- meta(docs,tag='id')`

`file.names`

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers and post a short explanation why your code works.